# Is it possible to display HTML page in Brightscript (Roku app)?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I've found a few old questions but nothing within the last year. Can Brightscript display an html page yet? I don't even want interaction with the page, just a display.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. Roku SDK does not include web browser component